# How would I set up my lighttpd.conf to serve a fastcgi app on a particular evhost virtual host?

Tags: configuration, lighttpd

I have

```
evhost.path-pattern = "/home/lighttpd/vhosts/%2/public"
```

When this pattern hits a certain host, let's say 'foo', I would like to use a fastcgi server. How do I configure just one of my virtual hosts?

So for foo, it should use:

```
fastcgi.server = ("/myapp"
    ...
)
```

For all other values of %2, it should do something else (such as default behavior of serving static content).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just don't use evhost.

```
$HTTP["host"] =~ "(www\.)?domain\.com" {
    server.document-root = "/foo/bar/baz"
    fastcgi.server = (
        "..."
        ),
    )
}
```

Comment: Never quite understood why evhosts was ever created when simple vhosts + some regex does the job 10x easier.

Comment: The only real use I've found for it is the one in the documentation, per user subdomains.  For everything else, I just use the above.

Comment: Obviously, I can do that, but I have like 10 sites serving parked pages, and I'd prefer to not have to manually keep track of them all.

Comment: I suppose this is the only option.